# Post With Solution?

Tags: discussion

stackoverflow has become a standard reference for computer issues that is often consulted by people wrestling with common issues.

I spent a while researching a good answer to a reasonably common short problem that is not answered in stackoverflow.  related questions were asked on stackoverflow and some answered.  (in my case, how to make doxygen print only some functions in the callgraph.  the best way is a little perlscript editing the generating dot file.)  so, now I have a common solution to a common answer.  I don't really need an answer myself any longer.  but I would be happy to help others by sharing it.  should I just post a question and then immediately an answer?

Comment: You can self answer, sure, even while you are writing the question.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: An overwhelming yes you can. It's literally built into the "ask a question" page at the bottom!